# How to handle missing data in psycopg2 upload

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I wrote a Python script that successfully connects to my Postgres database and also successfully uses rglob to get all .tsv files in a directory.

Some of the cells in these .tsv files have missing values.  Normally, when I'm uploading to Postgres, Postgres has no problem assigning these as NULL / empty.  But I am getting an error when doing this via psycopg2.

My code and the error are below:

```
create_table_1004 = """
create table if not exists mls_appraiser_form_1004mc_detailed (
    Status text,
    Street_Address_Full text,
    List_Price text,
    Sale_Price text,
    Age text,
    Sq_Ft_Total text,
    Lot_Size1 text,
    Listing_Date text,
    Sale_Date text,
    Close_Date text,
    DOM text,
    Unit_Number text,
    Zip_Code text,
    Original_List_Price text,
    Year_Built text,
    Lot_Size2 text,
    MLS_Number text
);
"""



def main():

    for file in pathlib.Path().rglob('*.tsv'):
        cur.execute(create_table_1004)
        with open(file,'r') as file_in:
            cur.copy_from(file_in, 'mls_appraiser_form_1004mc_detailed', sep='\t', null='\\N')

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tsv.uploader2.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "tsv.uploader2.py", line 65, in main
    cur.copy_from(file_in, 'mls_appraiser_form_1004mc_detailed', sep='\t')
psycopg2.DataError: missing data for column "original_list_price"
CONTEXT:  COPY mls_appraiser_form_1004mc_detailed, line 1: "    S   MLS #   Street Address  Price   DOM Beds Total  Bths    Sq Ft Total Lot Size    Postal City Property Sub Type..."
```

Comment: I suspect you need to skip the first row of the input (as it looks like column names and not values) and make sure to use the `columns=` argument to `cur.copy_from`...  see the assumption about columns in http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Comment: In the docs, `columns=` looks like it's supposed to be the column names as they appear in the source file, but I get an error when I try that: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Address"`